# What was the conspiratorial name of Roman Stanislaw Dmowski?

Tags: russia, poland

What name did [Roman Stanislaw Dmowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Dmowski) before he returned to Warsaw in 1905?

> in Autumn 1905 after the proclamation of the constitution in Russia, he [returned] to Warsaw, where he could live under his own name. *[niepodlegla](https://niepodlegla.dzieje.pl/postacie/roman-dmowski-1864-1939)*

I found that he wrote two novels e.g *Dziedzictwo* as 'Kazimierz Wybranowski'  but it was much later - in 1931.

My question is — what was his conspiratorial name before coming back to Warsaw in 1905? Under what name did he travel to Tokyo in 1904? I can't find this information.

Comment: @Michu93, please edit the question rather than replying in comments. the probability of an answer is diminished by every comment.  I've edited your source into the question and  clarified the stem sentence. Please fix any errors I introduced.  I'm not familiar with the term "conspiratorial name" - how is that different from "alias" or "pseudonym"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another pseudonym Dmowski used to use: *R. Skrzycki*

> The Liga Polska had been founded in the autumn of 1887; since 1893 it had been called Liga Narodowa. The National Democratic Party emerged from it in 1893. In this circle Dmowski found his permanent intellectual and political home and soon acquired a leading position. He became close friends above all with Johann Ludwig Popławski, ten years his senior, who together with Bohusz (Joseph Potocki) published the weekly magazine "Głos" in Warsaw (since 1886). Here, but also in other journals, Dmowski's first literary works appeared in 1890, among them a novella. He was already using the pseudonym "R. Skrzycki", under which his sensational contributions "Thoughts of a Modern Poland" were to appear first.
>
> […]
>
> In 1902, Dmowski again took over the management of the "Allpolnische Rundschau" and moved it to Krakow. As in 1895, this year's edition reflects Dmowski's particularly intensive collaboration. In it he also published, under his old pseudonym "R. Skrzycki", the "Thoughts of a Modern Pole", which then appeared in the following year (1903), supplemented and completed, as a book. They made a deep impression on the political consciousness of the Poles, both in contradiction and approval. These works actually established Dmowski's reputation as a political thinker.
>
> — Erich Maschke: "Roman Dmowski", Osteuropa, Vol. 10, No. 7 (April 1935), pp. 391–410. [jstor](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44929020), *[translated, LLC]*

This bibliography confirms many instances of usage of Skrzycki as a pen name:

[Bibliografia - Romana Dmowskiego (#PomnikDmowskiego. Wesprzyj budowę pomnika Romana Dmowskiego" [#Monument of Dmowskiego. Support the construction of the Roman Dmowski monument"])](http://romandmowski.edu.pl/index.php/bibliografia)

Apparently, the [Polish Wikipedia omits this info from his personal page](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Dmowski), but [reveals this pseudonym for the page on his *Thoughts of a Modern Pole*](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/My%C5%9Bli_nowoczesnego_Polaka).

Whether he used any other name for his travels to Tokyo is unknown to me, as nothing of these naming circumstances appears anywhere in the literature I consulted on this. But *in* Tokyo, in fact once he left the borders of Russia behind, my guesses tend to assume that his real name would be used in Japan?

The [Polish Wikipedia/Wikisource site only knows about these two aliases:](https://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Autor:Roman_Dmowski)

> Author: Roman Dmowski
> Roman Dmowski
> (Kazimierz Wybranowski, R. Skrzycki)